# 3-vote close - how's it going?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

### UPDATE: While the testing period has ended, this change has been well-received by the community so we have opted to not reset the votes needed to close/reopen to 5 while we look at data.

Please let me know if you have any concerns about this change in the planned process or if you feel the number of votes should be changed back at least temporarily. I'll be back in a few weeks with the results of the project.

---

Part of understanding the impact of three-vote closure is to understand what impact it's having on y'all. I'd like to ask anyone who feels up to it to **write an answer to this question** and to tell us about your experience over the past few weeks.

The sorts of things I'm interested in knowing (feel free to address all or none or add your own) -

- Did this help?
- Did it hurt?
- Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing? Less?

  - Are there things other than 3-vote close impacting your interest in reviewing?
- If you can't vote but do flag, did this make you more/less likely to flag?
- Would you prefer to go back to 5?
- Should it be permanent?
- What would you like me to look into when it comes to analyzing the data from the test?
- Were there any side-effects (good or bad) that you want me to be aware of?

These are merely prompts, so feel free to add anything I'm missing that you think is worth saying. This is focused on how you're feeling about it and what data you want me to look at, so don't feel like you need to analyze the data over the last 30 days - though you're welcome to if that's how you figure out what you feel.

If you have any outstanding questions, also feel welcome to ask them here.

The test will run until about Monday the 21st of June, at which point we'll be resetting the votes to close up to 5 while I review the responses here and dig into the data that we've been collecting.

Comment: Hi Catija, could SE.3D Printing be considered for a three vote limit, when/if it is introduced?  We have had an unofficial vote on it, and most voters are in favour of the three vote limit (5-1 in favour). Please see [Does this 3D Printing site want only three votes to close (or should we stick with five)?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/519/4762). Thanks.

Comment: @Greenonline I've just added the status-review tag - as a note, any time there's a request y'all want to bring to our attention that needs staff review (whether that's a feature request or a bug report, ect) add the status-review tag to it and we'll try to get back to you.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's been positive. With the lower numbers this site has often seen questions sitting on 3 or 4 close votes and hanging there (until we mods closed them). Now we're seeing things naturally close more often, which is good.

Answer (score 2):

> Would you prefer to go back to 5?

no

> Should it be permanent?

yes

> Did it make you more interested in close/reopen reviewing?

yes

Thank you